# SSH2 Keys and .ssh directory on Mac

Tags: macos, ssh

I am learning about private and public key pairs, so pardon my ignorance (if any).

I've created a total of three private / public key pairs via terminal using the ssh-keygen command in terminal.

I found out the application I was generating them for needed to have a blank passphrase, so I used this to delete the keypairs out (before continuing with generating another one)

rm id_rsa.pub  (I was in the .ssh directory already)

My question is.  I have no idea what Known_Hosts is (when I ls the .ssh directory) and I'm afraid my multiple generations left something in the Known_Hosts, despite me deleting out the .pub file each time before proceeding.

Any insight would be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This file pretty much keeps a "cache" of the previous hosts you've SSH'd into.  I just went ahead and removed an entry for 10.0.1.20 from the known hosts file on my machine.  When you SSH into this address (with no matching entry in known hosts). It will display something like:

```
The authenticity of host '10.0.1.20 (10.0.1.20)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is c1:f4:31:dc:94:33:a3:9d:36:3f:ad:92:20:b9:65:9f.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

If you hit yes an entry will be stored in Known Hosts as specified by the message:

```
Warning: Permanently added '10.0.1.20' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
```

If for some reason in the future the machine changes - perhaps an OS upgrade or some how its identity changes SSH will give you an error message in the future if you try to connect because the "key" in known hosts doesn't match the key of the machine you are connecting to.  The way to fix this problem (which we run into at work occasionally) is to remove the entry from known hosts.

Subsequent logins to this host (after the entry exists in your known_hosts) will not prompt you for the yes/no question.  You can delete this file if you like.

Comment: Thanks for the lightning fast response Jeef!